# python key codes and configparser assistance

Tags: python, python-2.7

python 2.7
how can i get the key code from my file not as a string

my file is settings.ini

```
[Settings]
keycode = 0x36
```

this the part of my code

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
config.read('settings.ini')
key = config.get('Settings', 'keycode')  # this is the key code i want ---> 0x36
```

for example

```
shell.sendkeys(key)
```

in this case senkeys would send

```
>> 0x36
```

i want it to send this

```
>> 6
```

the important part is i don't need a string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a typo: `key` should be `keycode`.

You can get character using [`int`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), [`chr`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#chr):

```
>>> key = '0x36'
>>> int(key, 16)  # Conver the string to int
54
>>> chr(int(key, 16)) # to character
'6'
```

Comment: i want key to represent 0x36 not as a string

Comment: @user3695962, `key = chr(int(config.get('Settings', 'keycode'), 16))`

Comment: nope need a hex code in integer form if that makes sense

Comment: @user3695962, `hex code` implies string. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @user3695962, If you want `6` instead of `'6'`: `key = int(chr(int(config.get('Settings', 'keycode'), 16)))`

Comment: shell.SendKeys(0x36)  the 0x36 is not a string and now instead of 0x36 i want key to represent 0x36 wich i get from my .ini file

Comment: @user3695962, Just use `key = int(config.get('Settings', 'keycode'))`.  54 is same value with 0x36. Try `54 == 0x36` in the shell.